# jQuery: How to make news ticker stop move when over on it

Tags: jquery

Does anyone help me to make the [news items](http://geschke.name/dev/newsticker/) stop moving when hover on it?

http://geschke.name/dev/newsticker/

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would do it like this:

```
$('ul#listticker').hover(pauseTicker, resumeTicker);

function pauseTicker() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

function resumeTicker() {
    interval = setInterval(newsticker, pause);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding this to the **same** `$(document).ready(function(){ });`, or move `function newsticker()` outside the document.ready function, which would be a bit better.

```
$("#listticker").hover(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, function() {
  interval = setInterval(newsticker, pause);
});
```

This cancels the interval when hovering, and resumes it when the mouse leaves.